# How do i use variables in other functions

Tags: java

I need help with my program. I need to use the variables "three" , "four" in two() but I don't know how.
Please help.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    one()
}

public static void one(){
    Integer three;
    Integer four;
    Integer five;
    three = 3;
    four = 4;
    two();


}
public static void two(){
    five = three + four;
    System.out.println(five);
}



}
```

Comment: The way you defined them they are local only to the method you declare them in. Declare them as class variables, outside of any method, then you can instantiate, or set their values, inside a method.

Comment: declare those variable as class variable. then create object of your class and call them. again understand basic class,object, function first.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them class variables, so bring them outside of your methods:

```
static Integer three;
static Integer four;
static Integer five;

public static void one(){
    three = 3;
    four = 4;
    two();    
}
```

And change `one()` to `one();`

---

Or you could make them parameters for your `two()` method:

```
public static void one(){
    Integer three;
    Integer four;
    three = 3;
    four = 4;
    two(three, four); // add parameters here
}
public static void two(Integer three, Integer four){
    Integer five; // declare five here
    five = three + four;
    System.out.println(five);
}
```

Comment: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field three
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field four

Comment: @bigfatlemon look at my updated code. I changed them to static variables.

Answer (score 1):

> "I need to use the variables "three" , "four" in two() but I don't know how. "

Pass them into the method as arguments

```
public static void two(Integer four, Integer three){
    int five = three + four;
    System.out.println(five);
}
```

Call it like this

```
two(four, three);
```

---

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        one();
    }

    public static void one() {
        Integer three;
        Integer four;
        three = 3;
        four = 4;
        two(four, three);

    }

    public static void two(Integer four, Integer three) {
        int five = three + four;
        System.out.println(five);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT : 7**

Answer (score 1):

You can try declaring them as fields in the class:

```
public class Main {
    private static int three;
    private static int four;
    private static int five;
    ...
}
```

if you do this, you don't have to declare them again in the method:

```
public static void one(){
    three = 3;
    four = 4;
    five = two();
}
```

---

Or you can try passing them as arguments to `two()` method, and return a value:

```
public static void two(int three, int four){
    return three + four;
}
```

then in `one()` method:

```
public static void one(){
    Integer three;
    Integer four;
    Integer five;
    three = 3;
    four = 4;
    five = two(three, four); // Assign the value returned by the 'two()' method
}
```

The way you choose *depends* on what you are trying to do. So you have to choose the one that fits better to your case.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

1. Declare `three` and `four` as `static` at the class level, and let `five` be the returned result of `two()`:

   ```
   public class Main {
       static Integer three;
       static Integer four;

       // more code
       public static void one() {
           three = 3;
           four = 4;
           Integer five = two();
           System.out.println(five);
       }

       public static Integer two() {
           return three + four;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Pass the variables in (and preferably drop the static declaration, forcing you to new an instance of your object to use the method `one()`):

   ```
   public class Main {
       public void one() {
           Integer five = two(3, 4);
           System.out.println(five);
       }
       public Integer two(Integer three, Integer four) {
           return three + four;
       }
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           new Main().one();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You probaly want:

```
public static void one(){
    int five = two(3,4);
}
public static int two(int three, int four){
    int five = three + four;
    System.out.println(five);
    return five;
}
```

Answer (score -6):

```
class F1() {
  int a;
  int b;
  void execute() {
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    two(this);
  };
}

void two(F1 f1) {
  int c = f1.a + f1.b;
}
```

or move local variable declarations at global scope

```
static int a;
void f1() {}
void f2() {};
```